# Tableau isNull then 0 calculated field

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have my tableau workbook and I'm currently counting by a field called ID - COUNT([Id]) - while this is great, on days with no activity my dashboard doesn't show ANYTHING and I want it to show zero if there was no activity - so I do I change this to count but also replace null with 0 (zero)?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you understand what Count([ID]) does. It returns the number records in the data source that have a non-null value in the column [ID].

Count() never evaluates to null. But if you have no rows at all in your data after filtering, then you'll get an empty result set -- i.e. view data will not have any summary data to show at all - whether null or zero.

Wrapping COUNT() in a call to ISNULL() or ZN() won't help in that case.

The solution is to make sure you have at least one data row per day, even if all other fields besides the date are null. Aggregation functions ignore nulls so padding your data like this should not disturb your results. The simplest way is to make a calendar table that has one row per day with nulls in most columns. Then use a Union to combine the calendar with your original data source. Then Count(ID) will return zero on days where there are no other records besides the calendar entry.

You can also get similar results using data blending, although with a bit more complexity.

Comment: The simplest way is to make a calendar table that has one row per day with nulls in most columns. Then use a Union to combine the calendar with your original data source. Then Count(ID) will return zero on days where there are no other records besides the calendar entry. --- is there a way for tableau to create this "table" without me needing to create on in the db?

Comment: Not really.   You can create in on fly at query time using custom sql depending on the data source, or merge it to a static list.